# OpenCart: Admin page Error

Tags: php, database, opencart

I have just migrated my OpenCart 1.5.6 to VPS host. The catalog page works fine, it shows a alert but ok, but when I actually navigate to the admin front, the page shows a error. Anybody know what's going on?

The error on the catalog is:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/database/mysql.php on line 6

The error on the admin is:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/database/mysql.php on line 6

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/journal2/classes/journal2_cache.php on line 43

Config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/logs/');
define('DIR_OPENCART', '/home/clara157/atacado/public_html/');

// DB

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_DATABASE', '*****');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');?>
```

admin/Config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.atacado.eliacessorios.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/clara157/public_html/atacado/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/clara_157/public_html/atacado/catalog/');

// DB

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '******');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
define('DB_DATABASE', '*****');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');?>
```

Comment: You used higher version of PHP installation. Or upgrade to latest OpenCart 2.2 which will solve the problem as they used mysqli :) 
Check to solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');`

in both side (catalog and amdin)